# Grafana "explore log histogram" in log dashboard panel

Tags: logging, histogram, grafana

I have (low volume) syslog messages going through loki into grafana 7.0.0.

I find myself exploring them via the Explore menu. It has a very useful histogram of the arrival time of the log messages.

I want to put a log panel into a dashboard so I don't have to click through the Explore menu and select queries, etc. However, when I add a log panel it doesn't have the histogram.

What is the right way to put that log message histogram into a dashboard panel? It would be a bonus if I could also use the histogram as a time selector (like in the Explore menu).